# Proof that number is not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $k$ is a positive integer, prove that $6^{16k+2}/2 - 1$ is not
a prime. I have no idea how to prove it.
Thank for advice.

Comment: The claim is only for _positive_ $k$ -- I wonder what happens when $k=0$? Then you get 17, which is prime. And 16 is the totient of 17, hmmm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Fermat's litte theorem to compute $6^{16k+2}\bmod 17$.

Comment: @Henning What's the meaning of "**User** Fermat's little theorem to compute ..."? If we interpret *user* as *use* the sentence is **wrong** because Fermat's little theorem cannot be used to compute a power. What Hagen is saying is to compute that number and then apply Fermat's little theorem on the result which implies the answer to the question.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Fermat's little theorem is exactly what you need to reduce the computation of this modular power. And what Hagen indended to say is exactly what he did say. I think you must either misunderstand which theorem we're talking about (google it!) or be ignorant of how one uses it to simplify the computation of modular powers. In any case, if you disagree with Hagen's answer, you can provide an answer of your own -- ***do not*** change his answer to say something else than what he intended to say!